# Marklogic How to save documents into single xml in file system

Tags: marklogic

The Qconsole return multiple document nodes.  But not know how to save all document nodes to file system into a single xml file.  I don't know why it only save the last document. ;-(( Thanks in advance.

my sample source code.

```
(:validate condition and concate values:)
declare function local:ifx($mnem,$val) as node()* {
   if(fn:exists($val)) 
   then xdmp:value(fn:concat("<meta name=""{$mnem}"" content=""",$val,""" />")) 
else ()
};

(:Loop and concat values:)
declare function local:forx($mnem,$vals) as node()* {
   for $val in $vals
       return xdmp:value(fn:concat("<meta name=""{$mnem}"" content=""",$val,""" />"))
};


declare function local:ETL($nodes as node()*) as node()*{

  for $n in $nodes
      let $v_id := $n/rec:record/meta:Metadata/meta:id
      let $v_ba := for $elem in $n/rec:record/meta:Metadata/meta:fundingSource
                      return if (fn:string-length($elem/meta:BugetCode/meta:code)= 1)
                            then fn:concat("0",$elem/meta:BugetCode/meta:code)
                            else $elem/meta:BugetCode/meta:code
  return
     <record url="dbfeed.iadb" mimetype="text/html" last-modified="NA">
          <metadata>
              {local:ifx("id",$v_id)}
              {local:forx("ba",$v_ba)}
          </metadata> 
      </record>
     )

};

(:find all documents within a year:)
let $docs := cts:search(
fn:doc(),
    cts:and-query((
                  cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("meta:Collection"),"EDS"),
                  cts:field-range-query("rd",">=","2016-01-01"),
                  cts:field-range-query("rd","<","2017-01-01")
                  ))
)

let $XML2016 :=
       for $i in (local:uredetl($docs))
       return $i

 return xdmp:save("/output/all-data-2016.xml") ,$XML2016)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$XML2016` has a sequence of items, but the second parameter for [`xdmp:save()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:save) expects a single `node()`.

In MarkLogic, when your XQuery version is declared as `1.0-ml`, [function mapping](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/enhanced#id_55459) is enabled by default. This means that the `xdmp:save()` function will be invoked once for each of the documents in the sequence. After all of those saves, the last document is the only one that you see.

If you disabled function mapping:

```
declare option xdmp:mapping "false";
```

and then executed your code, an **XDMP-ARGTYPE** error would be thrown, complaining that you have provided a sequence of nodes to the `xdmp:save()` function.

If you have multiple items that you want to save to the same file, you need to combine them first and then invoke save once with a with a single node, or save each with their own distinct filename, or maybe look to use [`zip:create()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:zip-create) instead.

Comment: Or, if you really want to create a single XML from all documents (as stated in your question), wrap $XML2016 into a wrapping element, which converts the sequence of doc nodes, into a single element node containing everything. Something like: `element wrapper { $XML2016 }`